# Should I suffix my variables with object type?

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

What's better?

```
private EditText mPhoneNumber;
private EditText mEmail;
private EditText mFirstName;
private EditText mLastName;
```

or

```
private EditText mPhoneNumberEditText;
private EditText mEmailEditText;
private EditText mFirstNameEditText;
private EditText mLastNameEditText;
```

I tend to think that in strong typed language, you don't need to suffix your variables with the type name. However, I don't have enough experience in Java to be sure of it.

Is this a non question? Or are there best practice regarding this matter?

Comment: I prefer the second one.. Prevents *typecasting* errors. But then again, this is *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: I would prefix it with the type in a short form and lowercase letter like: `private EditText m_editPhoneNumber`

Comment: Why not: `private EditText edtPhoneNumber;` too much `.NET` style?

Comment: Many development teams have a standards manual to cover this sort of question. If there is one, you should follow that.

Comment: This is a pretty religious question. I prefer to not have a prefix, but self-explaing names. I would go with `phoneNumberEditText`. And yes, I would scorch away those "m" prefixes with no mercy.

Comment: I personally **hate** the `m` prefix and prefer adding a prefix that indicates the type, Like `txt` for TextViews, `btn` for buttons (or ImageButtons or ToggleButtons), `img` for ImageViews, `edt` fot EditTexts, ...

Answer (score 0):

Though it is little longer with second type of naming conventions (`mPhoneNumberEditText`), I'l prefer them. You may later refer the value of `mPhoneNumberEditText` with variable name `mPhoneNumberValue`, which is more clear to read the code.